# Output values from a multidimension array in PHP

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array, output

I am learning how to use multidimension arrays in PHP and I need help to output the values.

The error i get is:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'name'in C on line 35.

I want to output the values like this:

```
name     quantity  
church   1
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['images'])) {

   $_SESSION['images'] = array();
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$test[]= $_POST['name'];
$test[]= $_POST['qty'];

 $_SESSION['images'][] = $test; 

}

  foreach ($_SESSION['images'] as $nom) {

      foreach ($nom as $val) {
        echo $val["name"];
      }
  }
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

 <head>
<title>Test Array</title>
    </head>


<body>


  <div id="holder">

<p>You have <?php echo count($_SESSION['images']);?> images</p>

   <div class="test">

<div><img src="images/church.jpg"></div>

<br>
 <form action="multidimention_array.php" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="name" id="name" value="church">

<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" size="1" value="1">

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send Value">
    </form>

      </div>

     <div class="test">

<div><img src="images/stellar.jpg"></div>

<br>
 <form action="multidimention_array.php" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="name" id="name" value="stellar">

<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" size="1" value="1">

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send Value">
    </form>

      </div> 
</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting / why isn't your own code working?

Comment: WOW people are quick to down-vote this question. Why not post a comment about what is lacking in this question instead of jumping to the down-vote button right ahead ? ...

Comment: @Epodax: This is the error i am getting:   Warning: Illegal string offset 'name'

Comment: If you want to avoid downvoting, read [ASK] and [MCVE]. Most importantly, you are not stating what the problem is by not describint your codes actual behaviour (i.e. output, error messages, etc).

Comment: Add the error message to your question by clicking [edit], and also include what line it is on.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($test)` and I think you will find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['name']` is being assigned to an integer index in `$test` and then `$_SESSION['images'][]` so `'name'` doesn't exist as a key when you loop.

Try the following:

```
$test['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$test['qty']  = $_POST['qty'];
```

**UPDATE**

Why are you doing two `foreach`s? The first will loop through the session images, which is an array containing your test array. The second loops through your test array. At this point, you are already in the `$test['name']` var, so you are effectively calling `$_SESSION['images'][0]['name']['name']`:

Try the following:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['images'] as $image) {
  echo $image['name'];
}
```

Comment: I did what you explained but i am getting this error: Warning: Illegal string offset 'name'...how can i solve that?

Comment: @AfrikDevelopeur Which line?

Comment: the error is : Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in C on line 24

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
$test[]= $_POST['name'];
```

This does not mean take the value for the key `name` from `$_POST` and save it under the same key in `$test`. What it means is take the value for the key `name` from `$_POST` and save it *under the first key that is free*. In practice that means it will end up with key `0` (asuming `$test` was empty to begin with). So there will be no $test['name'], and therefore no `$_SESSION['images']['name']` and no `$val['name'];`

The code you need to use is this:

```
$test['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$test['qty'] = $_POST['qty'];
```